# Obtener el URI de un Drawable en Res o Assets en Android

Tags: java, android

Cómo se puede obtener la ruta `URI` de un recurso `Drawable` interno, guardado en ¿`res` o `assets`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Para obtener la ruta [Uri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) de un recurso de `/assets` o `/raw`,

(obviamente para `/raw` cambia el folder) :

```
String archivo = "android.resource://"+  getPackageName() + "/assets/mi_recurso";
```

para obtener el [Uri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) sería con `Uri.parse()`:

```
 Uri ruta = Uri.parse(archivo);
```

#### Para obtener la ruta [Uri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) de un recurso dentro del folder `/res` es similar:

```
String archivo = "android.resource://"+  getPackageName() + "/drawable/mi_recurso";    
Uri ruta = Uri.parse(archivo);
```

incluso por medio del id del recurso:

```
String archivo = "android.resource://"+  getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.mi_recurso;    
Uri ruta = Uri.parse(archivo);
```

---

[getPackageName()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageName()) es un método para obtener el nombre del package de tu aplicación, pero tu podrías también escribir el nombre directamente, por ejemplo:

```
String archivo = "android.resource://com.miaplication.webserveis/drawable/mi_recurso";    
Uri ruta = Uri.parse(archivo);
```

Comment: Buenas @Elena acabo de implementar tu solución, buscando más sobre el tema he encontrado una función  que determina automaticamente el origen del recurso, getUriToResource() en http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602417/get-the-uri-of-an-image-stored-in-drawable

Comment: oh que bien, eso podría ser otra respuesta a esta pregunta, un método que recibe el contexto y el id del recurso para obtener el Uri! muy útil para otros desarrolladores!. Agregalá @Webserveis

Comment: Gracias  Jorge siempre que busco cosas sobre android estas presente y siempre son correctas , Gracias Jorge que nunca nos faltes!

Answer (score 1):

En una respuesta [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602417/get-the-uri-of-an-image-stored-in-drawable) la de @ceph3us hay una función que detecta automáticamente en que origen está el recurso.

```
public static final Uri getUriToResource(@NonNull Context context, @AnyRes int resId) throws Resources.NotFoundException {

    Resources res = context.getResources();

    Uri resUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE +
            "://" + res.getResourcePackageName(resId)
            + '/' + res.getResourceTypeName(resId)
            + '/' + res.getResourceEntryName(resId));

    return resUri;
}
```

**Su uso**

```
Uri origen = getUriToResource(this,R.drawable.mi_recurso);
```